# Battery Charging status showing unknown

Tags: android

I have developed my app named as Andro Sense.
 I don't know why in some devices, the battery charge status is shown unknown while its charging or discharging. 
Also if the connection type is mobile network. It sets up itself to unknown.
These 2 problems occurs concurrently.
Anybody with any solution?

Comment: On which devices with what version of android are you facing the issue. Also how are to figuring out the charge status and the connection type.

Comment: Actually its quite random. Though I have seen this problem mostly with Nougat devices and vendors such as ASUS n MOTO.

Comment: Well I don't know how to answer this question "how are to figuring out....". Please elaborate.

Comment: Any Solutions please?

Comment: Can you share the code as to how are you figuring out the connection type and the battery charge status?

Comment: It best advice to accompany your question with the code full code base where you have the or you think the problem is coming from. If you post a question with out a code that question happens to have high percentage of getting down votes and not getting answered. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) prior to asking a question and try to follow the structure suggested by the help documentation.